# await always thows SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in sequelize

Tags: node.js, async-await, sequelize.js

> Ubuntu 20
> Node 12.18.4
> NPM 6.14.6
> Sequelize 6.3.5

I followed the official guide and am so confused now.
After successfully configured **Sequelize** and connected, I tried to run (from official documentation)

```
await sequelize.authenticate();
```

It throws `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

Under the official get started page https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html, it clearly states:

> Most of the methods provided by Sequelize are asynchronous and therefore return Promises. They are all Promises , so you can use the Promise API (for example, using then, catch, finally) out of the box.
> Of course, using async and await works normally as well.

Comment: The methods return promises, that's true but the problem is that the function *where you have the `await`* must be `async function` (or an async arrow function `async () => {}`). It literally has to have the `async` word there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means in your function if you have to await you need to declare an async outside function:

```
async function() {
     await sequelize.authenticate();
}
```

or

```
const nameYourFunction = async () => {
     await sequelize.authenticate();
}
```

Remember to declare async before await or you can use the promise if you don't want to declare async await

```
const nameYourFunction = () => {
  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('nameYourFunction -> result', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('nameYourFunction -> error', error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that does solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use async function like this

```
getStateById: async (req, res) => {
              ^^^^^^

    sequelize.sequelize.transaction(async (t1) => {

        let state = await sequelize.state.findOne({
            where: {
                id: req.params.id
            }
        });

        let result = error.OK;
        result.data = state;

        logger.info(result);
        return res.status(200).send(result);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        logger.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send(error.SERVER_ERROR);
    });
}
```

async is necessary when you want to use await in your app it will be only used in async function type